# Modal pop-up non showing in asp.net core mvc web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have an ASP.NET CORE MVC based app. I am having a strange behavior when trying to show a modal popup with JQuery.

I have following div:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="form-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a button to show this div modal popup. When I click the button Javascript adds «in» to class so it becomes class="modal fade in", normally it should add «show». As a result the modal is not showing. So in the browser I enter dev mode and removed «in» and added «show» and it worked.

But I am wondering why my JQuery is adding «in» instead of «show».

Here is my JQuery:

```
jQueryModalGet = (url, title) => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
                $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
                $('#form-modal').modal('show');
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        return false;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I also checked the versions of Bootstrap (v. 4.3.1) and JQuery (v. 3.3.1), they seems to be ok with compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the issue.

For some strange reason I included two different versions of Bootstrap and JQuery at the same time so the conflict was happening in the modal show process.

I had:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

After removing:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And using only the local binded libs I resolved it!

Now it works like a charm.